# Not able to add host of EC2 to rancher

Tags: amazon-ec2, rancher

I got error like this.

> Error (Failed to find rancher-agent container)

I added host then docker will be added but when rancher agent part is going to configure then it will show error.

I am using rancher in my localhost using docker.

Comment: The information is not sufficient to debug. Please provide rancher server container logs and also any other rancher related containers. BTW when using the same host running rancher/server for registering, one common mistake a lot of first time users do is to fail to provide additional information for Agent IP address.

Comment: @leodotcloud how to get the server container logs. I don't have any idea of that. and you told that provide additional information for agent IP address, so how can I set that?

Comment: `docker logs <rancher server container id> > /tmp/rancher.server.log`

Comment: Also what version of rancher server are you running? Coz each version has different docs. See: https://rancher.com/docs/